# Creating a socks5 proxy from a Wireguard vpn on client

Tags: vpn, proxy, wireguard

I use ssh tunnel currently with Firefox and setup socks5 on it the point is that if the proxy is off and if there is problem with server then nothing loads,that's why I want to use socks proxy with wireguard.So when the wireguard is off and not connected the Firefox stops working as well. This is what I've found.

```
https://github.com/moparisthebest/wireguard-proxy
```

Since I'm newbie I don't know if this is what I'm looking for or not and how to use it.As my last plan I think a nasty work around could work(haven't tried yet though). To ssh myself over myself with -D tag so I can tunnel it just like I used to but this time instead of tunneling the server I can tunnel myself to put it on socks proxy.(I rather not use this nasty approach though)

Comment: I tried my nasty workaround and guess what it works.Any better way to achieve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well since nobody is answering first of all tunneling through myself totally worked as I excepted it created a socks proxy on my localhost and wireguard was on socks proxy then usable,then I went for a better way used dante server to do this first tried to setup the proxy on the server so I could access it via ip.com:1080 but unfortunately that didn't work and I think it was because all my important ports were already in use because my server has cpanel on it, so I installed dante server on my local machine and proxied the wireguard interface through it so again I have it on my localhost now but I don't open a stupid ssh connection no more just a bit of supervisor work to make it automatically work,when wireguard goes on now the dante server will go on in a few seconds at most so it's totally automatic now thanks to dante and supervisor and everything is great now.

I didn't expect to get no answer here, becuase I'm a newbie here and I didn't expect at the end I answer my own question.

Comment: Hey man, you didn't get any answers here, but that still can happen, and it may have suggestions you didn't think of. Sometimes you get an answer years later. It's not because you're new. And you know?! By posting a question here, if you put effort in it, you come up with new ideas, just by posting. Sometimes that is enough to find out the solution yourself. It took you 9 days to find an answer. That is not bad! Keep using this site. Many times it has helped me, and many times it has not. But many times it has...

Comment: PS: try to use better punctuation - that makes it easier to read. The better you present your question, with screenshots, code snippets, and with all things you tried, the more response you will get.

Comment: @SPRBRN Thanks pal you are right.I know I'm new here but I used stackoverflow for a long time.I just didn't expect to get nothing here because all the other questions had so many answers :D And yeah,I gotta work on my punctuation a little bit more I guess.